# convert long string to integer list

Tags: import, string-manipulation

at first, i would like to thank all the people here. i'm working with mathematica for half a year now and always found great advice and tricks.

now, i came up with a problem i couldn't find a solution for. from a file, i import a string with around 23 mio. characters which is reasonably fast (it acutually is a dna sequence). i then want to split this string into its characters and convert each of them to an integer number.

my first, naive approach was the following:

```
MaxMemoryUsed[]/1024^2//N
AbsoluteTiming[list=Characters[a]/.{"A"->1,"T"->2,"G"->3,"C"->4};]
ByteCount[list]/1024^2//N
MaxMemoryUsed[]/1024^2//N
```

which creates the following output:

```
134.286
{13.301206,Null}
702.261
1976.42
```

as you can see, the timing is quite good but the memory usage during the process is horrible.
my next approach was reading from a stream and convert each character to an integer instantly:

```
MaxMemoryUsed[]/1024^2//N
string=StringReplace[string,{"A"->"1","T"->"2","G"->"3","C"->"4"}];
str=StringToStream[string];
AbsoluteTiming[list=Table[ToExpression[Read[str,Character]],{i,1,StringLength[string]}];]
Close[str];
ByteCount[list]/1024^2//N
MaxMemoryUsed[]/1024^2//N
```

which results in

```
134.281
{176.502736,Null}
702.252
813.208
```

as yo can see, this approach needs way less memory but takes considerably longer. my question now is, if there is another memory efficient way to do this which is faster than my second try?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the string stored in a file as one long line, or broken up in some way ?

Comment: Can't test right now, but givent hat the slow part in your second approach is turning the string of numbers into a list, what about something like `ToExpression@StringCases[string, DigitCharacter]`, or `ToCharacterCode@string - 48`

Comment: to wrap this up, the string is broken up into many [lines of constant length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string = StringJoin @@ RandomChoice[{"A", "T", "G", "C"}, 30000000];
```

This seems to take little memory

```
Boole[# === 65] + 2 Boole[# === 84] + Boole[# === 71] 3 + 
   Boole[# === 67] 4 & /@ ToCharacterCode[string]
```

but twice as long as

```
ToCharacterCode[
  StringReplace[
   string, {"A" -> "1", "T" -> "2", "G" -> "3", "C" -> "4"}]] - 48
```

Compiling the first solution makes it faster than the second

```
Compile[{{x, _Integer}}, \[Piecewise] {
    {1, x === 65},
    {2, x === 84},
    {3, x === 71},
    {4, x === 67}
   }, RuntimeAttributes -> Listable]@ToCharacterCode[string]
```

Comment: Interestingly in version 7 the first method takes 62 seconds and ~2GB of memory, while the second takes only 1.7 seconds and ~1GB (no more than required for `string`).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard string requires as many bytes as characters. Are you using a billion character string?

Comment: I mean the memory required for the creation of `string` using the code you provided`. (What do you get for `MaxMemoryUsed[]` right after?)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, 650MB, but I forgot I was actually restarting the kernel and loading the string from the front end every time, so after that the memory in use is the same as the max memory used, which is 49MB

Comment: Ah, that would be wise to find the actual memory used, wouldn't it? :)  (I mean what *you're* doing would be wise.)

Comment: If I use `string = ReadList["big.txt", String];` it takes only ~105MB on my system.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, good, I had tested with Import which must be worse. But I'm actually using the front end without importing :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6419/discussion-between-rojo-and-mr-wizard)

Comment: The new Compile method with `Piecewise` is great.  The one with `Boole` didn't work on my machine, but even without `RuntimeAttributes -> Listable` this is fast and uses little memory.  (blast, copied the wrong version; you know what I mean!)

Comment: the compiled version is great: elegant and efficient

Answer (score 8):

OK, we don't need command-line tools for this. We can do better, faster and with less memory.

Lets create a test file with 30 million letters:

```
Export["tmp/sequence.txt", StringJoin@RandomChoice[{"A", "C", "G", "T"}, 30000000]]
```

The trick is to make the conversion parallel on all data and to keep packet-arrays. First we define a parallel, compiled function which does the conversion for one character:

```
repl = Compile[{{n, _Integer, 0}},
  If[n == 65, 1,
   If[n == 67, 2,
    If[n == 71, 3,
     If[n == 84, 4, -1]
     ]
    ]
   ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
  Parallelization -> True
  ]
```

Yes, those `If`s look pretty awful, but they get compiled down while `Switch` or `Which` doesn't. See, that we don't read characters, we read the ASCII codes instead which is a nicely packed integer array:

```
MaxMemoryUsed[]/1024^2 // N
AbsoluteTiming[dna = repl[Developer`ToPackedArray[ReadList["tmp/sequence.txt", Byte]]];]
MaxMemoryUsed[]/1024^2 // N
```

Here this takes 2 seconds and less than 500 MB of memory.

### Timings

I timed all methods on my machine. I really don't know how image_doctor got his method so fast. It was the slowest here (native Linux, SSD, Intel i7 extreme, 32 GB Ram). I didn't preload the data. If a method used a string, I used `Import`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Currently fastest method

I thought, that it's Rojos `Piecewise` construct was faster, but as it turns out this was cosmic radiation since the ugly nested `If`s and the `Piecewise` solution produce exact the same compiled code. The full test code consists of a sequence of only 3 million digits

```
Export["sequence.txt", StringJoin@RandomChoice[{"A", "C", "G", "T"}, 3000000]];
```

which is called 100 times.

**halirutan**

```
f = Compile[{{n, _Integer, 0}}, 
  If[n == 65, 1, If[n == 67, 2, If[n == 71, 3, If[n == 84, 4, -1]]]], 
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
  Parallelization -> True];

Mean@Table[First@AbsoluteTiming[
    f[ToCharacterCode[Import["tmp/sequence.txt"]]];], {100}]

(* Out[2]= 0.181717 *)
```

**Rojo compiled to "C" and parallel**

```
f = Compile[{{x, _Integer}}, Piecewise[{{1, x === 65}, 
           {2, x === 84}, {3, x === 71}, {4, x === 67}}], 
       CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True];

Mean@Table[First@AbsoluteTiming[f[
      ToCharacterCode[Import["tmp/sequence.txt"]]];], {100}]

(* Out[3]= 0.183226 *)
```

Note here, how mystical it is, that `Piecewise` (and `If`s with *then* branch (!)) get compiled correctly to "C", while `Switch` and `Which` stays in a `MainEvaluate` call.

Comment: I don't think the memory can be brought below twice the size of the packed array of integers. Unless you do a very slow in place modification. Your If version is faster than my Boole, +1. The parallelization in my computer doesn't make it faster this time. And The compilation to C I bet it doesn't if its just for one. I don't have a suitable compiler here :(

Comment: @Rojo The compilation to "C" is not to speed up the computation itself! It's that the vector-registers are used which is most likely not done by the Mathematica-VM.

Comment: Any reason why you used nested `If[]`s as opposed to a `Switch[]`?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, the switch doesn't compile and stays as `MainEvaluate` in the code.

Comment: The piecewise version in my edit generates the exact (except for defaulting to 0 instead of -1) same code (CompilePrint checked) as the nested If, avoiding the uglyness :D

Comment: @Rojo Yes, I have seen it but I didn't want to steal your idea.

Comment: +1 for benchmarking and introducing parallelization

Comment: @halirutan weird that `Piecewise` compiles and `Which`/`Switch` don't. Regarding vector instructions, *Mathematica* by default specifies `-O2`, but you need `-O3 -march=native` or at least `-ftree-vectorize` to generate those. (Unless you're using the Intel compiler.)

Comment: @halirutan The difference in timing is in the file structure as far as I can tell, I used a 10,000 line file. It may be that `IntegerDigits` is sensitive to the length of the integer.

Comment: @halirutan The OP hasn't yet responded to the original question as the file structure, so the correct solution may still be unclear.

Comment: a length of 10,000 lines or more is quite common in the files i process (fasta: see comment at the question). but as i want to be able to read different file formats, i accept to slow the code down by first generating a large string which then is processed further. reading the file and returning the string takes only a couple of seconds which is fine for me.

Comment: I've probably done something incorrectly, but the final example seems to produce `dna` with only values of zero in it for me?

Comment: @image_doctor I made a complete example in the last part. Do you have a C-compiler installed?

Answer (score 4):

I read 30 million characters stored in around 10,000 lines in a text file into a list of integers like this.

```
dna = Flatten[IntegerDigits /@ ReadList["!cat /tmp/dna.tmp | tr [ACGT] [1234]"]];
//AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.766828, Null}

Memory usage was 0.93GB for 29.6 mega characters.

The 0.93GB is effectively the space required for the 30 million integers. I guess this storage amount could be compressed if required as the underlying alphabet only has 4 symbols.

Comment: That's the space required if they aren't packed. Otherwise they take 4 bytes each, so 120MB

Comment: Do you mean I should add `ToPackedArray`, I hadn't spotted anyone else using it? Is there some automatic packing going on somewhere ? Ah I see @halirutan has used it :)

Comment: If you add ToPackedArray, you'll get an array of 120MB, but if you had to add it its because in the process it got unpacked, so somewhere along the line it used the 0.93GB. Some alternatives never leave the packed array realm. And those, use 2x120MB because they have to create a copy to turn the array into what the OP wants, and MMA always copies everything :P

Comment: The 0.93GB was the reported `ByteCount` for the variable `dna`. Is it automatically expanding up the report of memory usage from the `dna` variable that has somewhere been automatically packed?

Comment: It just means that the dna variable is unpacked then. Pass it through ToPackedArray and then it should report 120MB

Answer (score 4):

On my PC, using a lookup table is slightly faster than @halirutan's `If` or `Piecewise` method.

```
Export["tmp/sequence.txt", StringJoin@RandomChoice[{"A", "C", "G", "T"}, 30000000]]

lookup = ConstantArray[0, 256];
lookup[[ToCharacterCode["ACGT"]]] = Range[4];

f = Compile[{{x, _Integer}, {lut, _Integer, 1}}, lut[[x]],
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True];

AbsoluteTiming[f[ToCharacterCode[Import["tmp/sequence.txt"]], lookup];]
```

Takes 3.1198962s, compared to 3.2079074 with the `Piecewise` code in @halirutan's answer.

If you don't care what the function returns for characters other than A,C,G,T, this is even faster:

```
f = Compile[{{x, _Integer, 1}},
   UnitStep[x - 65] + UnitStep[x - 84] + UnitStep[x - 71] + UnitStep[x - 67]];
AbsoluteTiming[f[ToCharacterCode[Import["sequence.txt"]]];]
```

Takes 2.9723774s

(Probably because `UnitStep` can somehow use SIMD instructions and `If` and `Part` cannot)

Comment: your first version is faster for me as well.

Answer (score 3):

Though not quite as fast as Rojo's second method this is a little shorter and uses less memory on my machine:

```
ToCharacterCode @ string /. {65 -> 1, 84 -> 2, 71 -> 3, 67 -> 4}
```

You could also read your data as bytes to bypass `ToCharacterCode` like this:

```
BinaryReadList["gen.txt"] /. {65 -> 1, 84 -> 2, 71 -> 3, 67 -> 4}
```

*However, his new compiled form is as fast and uses much less memory.*

#### Comparison

First generating test data:

```
string = StringJoin @@ RandomChoice[{"A", "T", "G", "C"}, 30000000];

DumpSave["bigGen.txt", string];
```

`Quit[]`, then:

```
ToCharacterCode[StringReplace[
     ReadList["bigGen.txt", String],
     {"A" -> "1", "T" -> "2", "G" -> "3", "C" -> "4"}]] - 48 // 
  Timing // First

MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> 2.075
>
> 850227296

`Quit[]` again, and:

```
BinaryReadList["bigGen.txt"] /. {65 -> 1, 84 -> 2, 71 -> 3, 67 -> 4} // Timing // First

MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> 2.387
>
> 614962712

Now with Rojo's compiled piecewise form:

```
f = Compile[{{x, _Integer}},
   \[Piecewise]{{1, x === 65}, {2, x === 84}, {3, x === 71}, {4, x === 67}}];

f /@ BinaryReadList["bigGen.txt"] // Timing // First

MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> 2.262
>
> 254977528

This should be even better in Version 8 with the enhanced Compile.

Comment: Liked the BinaryReadList